# How to add eventListener to every cells of first column?

Tags: javascript, html-table, addeventlistener, innertext

This code works just for first cell of first column. When i click the cell, an alert shows innerText of cell. I would like the alert to be launched on each cells of the first column and displays the text of the cell clicked. How to do that? I'm new to javascript sorry and thanks in advice for your time.

```
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'andrea',
  password: '*********',
  database: 'andrea',
  charset: 'utf8'
});

//html string that will be send to browser
var reo ='<html><head><title>Table From SQL</title></head><body><h1>Table From SQL</h1>{${table}}</body></html>';

//sets and returns html table with results from sql select
//Receives sql query and callback function to return the table
function setResHtml(sql, cb){
  pool.getConnection((err, con)=>{
    if(err) throw err;

    con.query(sql, (err, res, cols)=>{
      if(err) throw err;

      var table =''; //to store html table

      //create html table with data from res.
      for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        table +='<tr><td id="peso" style="cursor:pointer">'+ res[i].peso +'</td><td>'+ res[i].vita +'</td><td>'+ res[i].data +'</td></tr>';
      }
      table ='<table border="1" id="table1"><tr><th>Peso</th><th>Vita</th><th>Data</th></tr>'+ 
      table +'</table>';
      table = table += '<script>var peso = window.document.getElementById("peso");'+
        'peso.addEventListener("click", functionOnClick, false);'+
        'function functionOnClick(){alert(peso.innerText);}</script>'

      con.release(); //Done with mysql connection

      //const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);


      return cb(table);
    });
  });
}



let sql ='SELECT * FROM registropeso';

//create the server for browser access
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  setResHtml(sql, resql=>{
    reo = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(reo, 'utf-8');
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);

/*
server.listen(8080, ()=>{
  console.log('Server running at //localhost:8080/');
});
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select every element that is the first `td` in a row. You can then loop through these and add the event listeners. `document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td:first-child");` will select these elements. Within the event listener, you can make use of `this` to get the element that has been clicked.

```js
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'andrea',
    password: '*********',
    database: 'andrea',
    charset: 'utf8'
});

//html string that will be send to browser
var reo = '<html><head><title>Table From SQL</title></head><body><h1>Table From SQL</h1>{${table}}</body></html>';

//sets and returns html table with results from sql select
//Receives sql query and callback function to return the table
function setResHtml(sql, cb) {
    pool.getConnection((err, con) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        con.query(sql, (err, res, cols) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            var rows = ''; //to store html rows

            //create html table with data from res.
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                rows += `<tr><td style="cursor:pointer">${res[i].peso}</td><td>${res[i].vita}</td><td>${res[i].data}</td></tr>`;
            }

            var table = `<table border="1" id="table1"><tr><th>Peso</th><th>Vita</th><th>Data</th></tr>${rows}</table>`;

            table += `
                <script>
                function functionOnClick() {
                    alert(this.innerText);
                }

                var pesoElements = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td:first-child");
                pesoElements.forEach(function(peso) {
                    peso.addEventListener("click", functionOnClick, false);
                })
                </script>`;

            con.release(); //Done with mysql connection

            //const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);


            return cb(table);
        });
    });
}
```

Note: I have made use of [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to clean things up a bit in the code.

Comment: your solution works, thanks but can u explain me "pesoElements.forEach(function(peso) " what do? and what is peso? it is not an assigned variable.

Comment: @Andrea it is looping through the returned nodes, using a [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. When looping through, `peso` will take on the current value of the array (or [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) in this case). So in the function, `peso.addEventListener` is adding an event listener to each node within the NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

Update part of your code as below:

```
for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        table +='<tr><td id="peso" style="cursor:pointer">'+ res[i].peso +'</td><td>'+ res[i].vita +'</td><td>'+ res[i].data +'</td></tr>';
      }
      table ='<table border="1" id="table1"><tr><th>Peso</th><th>Vita</th><th>Data</th></tr>'+ 
      table +'</table>';
      table = table += '<script>var peso = window.document.getElementById("peso");'+
        'peso.addEventListener("click", functionOnClick, false);'+
        'function functionOnClick(){alert(peso.innerText);}</script>'
```

to

```
for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        table +='<tr><td id="peso'+i+'" style="cursor:pointer">'+ res[i].peso +'</td><td>'+ res[i].vita +'</td><td>'+ res[i].data +'</td></tr>';
        table += '<script>var peso = window.document.getElementById("peso'+i+'");'+
        'peso.addEventListener("click", functionOnClick, false);'+
        'function functionOnClick(){alert(peso.innerText);}</script>'
      }
      table ='<table border="1" id="table1"><tr><th>Peso</th><th>Vita</th><th>Data</th></tr>'+ 
      table +'</table>';
```

**Explanation:**

You are assigning same ID to multiple TDs through loop.

Concatenating **i** will make ID of each TD unique.

Comment: For this to work, `table = table += '<script>var peso = window.do ...` must be within the for loop.

Comment: @Khushbu I'm sorry but your suggestion doesen't work, I appreciate your help